# Unity 2D flickers while running

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, flicker

i have a problem.  After I set up the Cinemachine for my 2D game, the game started to flicker when I am running.  So when I started running in the game all textures flicker.
I am new to Unity and have no idea how to solve the problem.

Comment: Depends on how you move your character. Please show us some code.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Cinemachine Cam --> Body---> then increase the Dead Zone Width, and Dead Zone Height a little bit only.

Hope this helps.
[check the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jj8Ek.png)